# Azure disk speed

Tags: azure

I am working on a numerical model that is disk bound and I was comparing the performance using PassMark on my in-house environment compared to Standard D2 Azure computer. Does anyone know why the Sequential writes are slow in Azure?

```
                    Computer A  Computer B          Azure D2         
Disk Mark           4274        1328                6343 MBytes/s
Sequential Read     259.2       20                  1701 MBytes/s
Sequential Write    450.4       289.1               13.7 MBytes/s
Random Seek + RW    272.1       58.1                39.6 MBytes/s
```

Computer A is a virtual machine with SAS network storage

Computer B is a virtual machine with SATA network storage

Comment: This is for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d-series virtual machines don't use premium storage. Which means they are slower by default and only have a temp disk wich uses ssd.

When using ds-series you get premium storage, which means you get a faster ssd attached to the machine.

When using a write-intensive application know that the disk caching policy is "Read-Only" for all the Premium data disks. If you switch this off you will get better performance on your drives.

Here is an overview of premium storage: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage-preview-portal/

Answer (score 0):

I've conducted performance tests of Azure VM Premium SSD Managed Drive. I must say the results are far from perfect. Sequential speeds are at around 60 MB/s, random writes are around 1MB/s.
http://saplin.blogspot.com/2018/08/azure-vm-ssd-performance-is-25x-slower.html?m=1